# How to scale y-axis on a seaborn heatmap to span across the entire chart?

Tags: seaborn, heatmap, axis, axis-labels, yaxis

I'm trying to reduce the number of y-ticks on a seaborn heatmap and relabel them, but I can't seem to make the y-ticks span the entire heatmap.

```
num_yticks = int(num_freqs/2)
yticks = np.arange(num_yticks)
yticklabels = np.logspace(np.log2(2),np.log2(150),num = num_yticks,base=2, dtype=np.float16)

sns.heatmap(data, ax=axs[0][0], vmin=-.4, vmax=.4, yticklabels=yticklabels, cbar_kws={"label": "Frequency Power"}, cmap='PRGn')

axs[0][0].axes.invert_yaxis()
```

[heatmap with a reduced number of y-ticks that only spans to about half the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMaXR.png)

I've already tried using set_yticks() and set_yticklabels() but still encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the the desired result by ensuring that my `ytick` variable followed the same scaling as my heatmap.

```
num_freqs = data.shape[2]

yticks = np.arange(num_freqs, step=2)
yticklabels = [round(i,1) for i in np.logspace(np.log2(2),np.log2(150),num = len(yticks),base=2, dtype=np.float16)]

sns.heatmap(data, ax=axs[0][0], vmin=-.4, vmax=.4, cbar_kws={"label": "Frequency Power"}, cmap='PRGn')
axs[0][0].set(xlabel="Time (sec)", ylabel="Frequency (Hz)")

axs[0][0].set_yticks(yticks)
axs[0][0].set_yticklabels(yticklabels, rotation = 0)
axs[0][0].axes.invert_yaxis()
```

[image: image of updated heatmap]